# ng-show if json returns [false] with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm new to angulars and i working on a project where i want a div to only show when the json data returns `[false]`. i sometimes get the json to return `[false]` when there is no results from the query.

JS

```
 .controller('query_ctrl', function($scope, $http){ $http.get('http://localhost/db/templates/search/matches.php').success(function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.matches=data;
           });
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="query_ctrl">
<div align="center" ng-show ="$scope.matches='false'">json returned false 
 </div>

<div align="center" ng-show ="$scope.matches!='false'">json returned true 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you are using a string false if its a boolean value just leave as ng-show = "matches" no need of $scope in HTML

Comment: Even if you have googled it, you will surely get better code to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reference $scope in the HTML.

```
<div ng-controller="query_ctrl">
<div align="center" ng-show ="matches=='false'">json returned false 
 </div>

<div align="center" ng-show ="matches!='false'">json returned true 
 </div>
</div>
```

Also, as the comment above says - i'm unsure why you're comparing the value to the string 'false', I assume you want to compare to boolean false. See below.

```
<div ng-controller="query_ctrl">
<div align="center" ng-show="matches==false">json returned false 
 </div>

<div align="center" ng-show ="matches!=false">json returned true 
 </div>
</div>
```

You could make the ng-show expressions more concise by just having matches as the expression, ng-show will evaluate if it is a truthy value or not, see below.

```
<div ng-controller="query_ctrl">
    <!-- Will show if matches is a false value -->
    <div align="center" ng-show="!matches">json returned false 
     </div>

    <!-- Will show if matches is a truthy value -->
    <div align="center" ng-show ="matches">json returned true 
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `ng-show="matches"` and `ng-show="!matches"` mayhaps

Comment: @Mackan That is how I would write it, didn't want to alter his code too much.. I will add in a third snippet :)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing one `=` in the first ng-show and also you don't need to refence the $scope, should be:

```
ng-show ="matches=='false'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems fine except $scope is not used in html file.

```
<div ng-controller="query_ctrl">
<div align="center" ng-show ="matches=='false'">json returned    false 
</div>

 <div align="center" ng-show ="matches!='false'">json returned true 
 </div>
 </div>
```

replace $scope.matches with matches only.

"ng-show" or "ng-if" both could be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define comparison operation near ng-show, you can even just do like :

```
<div align="center" ng-show ="$scope.matches"> // Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('query_ctrl', function($scope, $http){ $http.get('http://localhost/db/templates/search/matches.php').success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.matches="data here";
       }).error(function(error){
         console.log("Error here");
         $scope.matches="Error here"};
})
```

Then on the HTML file you can write:

```
<div ng-controller="query_ctrl">
<div align="center" ng-show ="matches=='data here'">json returned true 
</div>

<div align="center" ng-show ="matches=='Error here'">json returned false 
</div>
</div>
```

All you had to do was loose that $scope in the html this is because HTML page is considered as the scope.